# IPN response in sandbox transaction?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Does PayPal provides IPN response during sandbox usage? I create no payment via NVP call, redirect to PayPal site, login, "pay" (in sandbox mode) and go to the return page which I set in my payment call. But there is no ping from PayPal to my IPN address :(

Should it work in sandbox, or users are able to test IPN responses only in production mode?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you checked in the sandbox account whether there is IPN sent to the URL? You can go to http://sandbox.paypal.com, login with the sandbox login. Then, go to this link: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history where you can see the IPN history page.

Comment: Make sure the HTTP status is 200, otherwise there may be issue with the IPN URL

Comment: Sandbox IPN history is empty, not a single record. IPN URL address is configured correctly, and returns 200. No idea what is going on :(

Comment: Did you make sure that you are passing the IPN url in your code ? If you don't pass in the code make sure you have set the IPN url in your sandbox account .

Comment: Yes I pass my IPN URL in code (and also it's set in sandbox account).

Answer (score 0):

Propably found the solution. I passed in my PayPal URL useraction=commit parameter. When I removed it, and used doexpressCheckoutPayment, everything works fine ...